# XMPP and libjingle connection using IP address

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, p2p, google-talk, libjingle

I am developing a P2P application where UserA knows UserB's IP address and request a connection. It is not possible to log-in to any Google Talk or similar account, we have to use just the IP address.

Then, **is it true that I cannot use XMPP API or libjingle?** (it looks like it requires a "login process"). **Any API or Java library suggested to do it?**

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're developing a web-based application, browser security is going to prevent you from making a direct peer-to-peer connection between two clients.

You can use the [App Engine Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html) to handle real-time communication between two clients; using this, both clients will connect to the App Engine server to exchange messages.